# Is Multiple Inheritance that bad in this particular scenario?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Currently I'm trying to understand "evilness" of MI. I've just watched a video on youtube where a js guy speaks against inheritance. Here is his example (I've rewrite it in C++):

```
struct Robot
{ void drive(); };

struct MurderRobot : public Robot
{ void kill(); };

struct CleanerRobot : public Robot
{ void clean(); };

struct Animal
{ void poop(); };

struct Dog : public Animal
{ void bark(); };

struct Cat : public Animal
{ void meow(); };
```

Then he suggested a new class `MurderRobotDog`, which, from his point of view, can't be done gracefully by means of inheritance. Surely, it can't be done by means of single inheritance. But I don't see any problem to do that with MI.

I think we could create a base class `BarkingObject`, which would have all barking stuff. Then the Dog inherits from the Animal, which has common poop(), and from the `BarkingObject`. And when you need a killing dog-robot, it must inherit from the `BarkingObject` and the `MurderRobot`. It makes more sense. The `MurderRobotDog` can't inherit from a live creature, because then it becomes alive and that contradicts with the definition of a robot. Of course, for that you have to use multiple inheritance that is considered to be EVIL by many people. It's unfortunate, as it seems we can't efficiently reuse different unrelated (you don't need poop() in order to bark(), and the robot case confirms this assertion) functionality without it.

What is your arguments against my suggestion?

Comment: of course you can write a `MurderRobotDog` using multiple inheritance. The problem with multiple inheritance is not that it is "EVIL", the problem is that it comes with complications that you simply don't have when you don't use it

Comment: Its not even multiple ineritance which makes things complicated but common bases and name clashes. Unless there is a specific reason for such a design just avoid it. Just makes no sense to talk about this in the context of some otherwordly toy example.

Comment: @OleksijPlotnyc'kyj For starters, yes. Are you aware of virtual inheritance? Just another dimension to reason about and to decide. Its best to keep things as simple as possible. This doesn't mean that MI is inherently evil. If it makes sense in your design go for it. E.g i think iostreams is an example where it perfectly makes sense.

Comment: fwiw, calling something "evil" never helped anybody. The famous "goto is evil" is a misquote, the original title is "go to statement considered harmful" and it comes with a in-depth explanation of why it is considered harmful. You need to know why not and what are the downsides, only then you can make a well founded decision to use it or not. My advise: Don't trust anybody who calls something "evil"

Comment: "we can't efficiently reuse [...] functionality without it [MI]" - seems more like a failure of imagination than a statement of fact. Besides, I'm not sure what's so efficient about inheriting a bunch of messy and possibly conflicting stuff from multiple base classes, instead of containing them and making it clear where given names/behaviour come from.

Comment: Seems too broad/opinionated & likely to result in counterarguments w/ other contrived examples. e.g.: entities other than robots can murder & drive, so what if we need a murderous car-cat? and so on, etc. It's the "js guy"'s opinion that MI is bad. It's yours that it isn't and that we must disprove you. Neither of those opinions are facts, until they're backed up with hard data, such as 'this project used MI here, found this problem, & fixed it by composition'. A lot of that comes from experience & isn't concisely summarised or specific enough for SO. Plus, we surely have such threads already!

Comment: Multiple inheritance is considered evil by people who haven't taken the time to understand it. And by the marketing folks for Java.

Comment: Multiple inheritance isn't evil.  Composition (multiple interfaces) isn't evil, nor is it better-or-worse than multiple inheritance.  They are just different strategies more-or-less suitable depending on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A multiple inheritance implementation is an old-fashioned way of solving these sorts of problems.

*Composition* is the new way.

You define *interfaces* which describe a particular behaviour or set of behaviours:

```
struct Murderer
{
    virtual ~Murderer() = default;
    void kill();
};

struct Pooper
{
    virtual ~Pooper() = default;
    void poop();
};
```

Actual things, like a cat, dog, or robot, inherit (i.e. implement) these interfaces accordingly. You use a `dynamic_cast` or similar runtime technique to *query* an object for an interface before making the appropriate action.

Comment: How is this related to composition?

Comment: Probably referring to something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance (don't simply ignore the *warning: confusing* at the top). Composition is what happens when you implement those interfaces in the suggested way.

Comment: Most would take "composition" to mean that the 'derived' object contains (values of or references to) instances of the other classes and can access their behaviour that way. I am not a software architecture expert but hadn't heard it used re interfaces before.  I also didn't realise it was recommended/modern to have to `dynamic_cast`, ever really!

Comment: @Timbo That article certainly is confusing, since before it seems to support your point, it first defines composition as "the principle that classes should achieve polymorphic behavior and code reuse by their **composition (by containing instances of other classes that implement the desired functionality) rather than inheritance**". Inheriting from an interface is still inheritance (albeit perhaps with fewer pitfalls).

Comment: Yes, `dynamic_cast` is slow as hell and requires RTTI. My impression is that most c++ developers tend to avoid polymorphism if possible or use it for higher level code which is just called very seldomly.. Instead templates and Concepts are more common and preferable IMO if possible.

Comment: Composition, as I understand it, is, to put it simply, having a `std::vector` member instead of inheriting from it. But maybe i'm mistaken.

Comment: Composition isn’t new. The GoF design pattern book is over a quarter century old and the patterns in there mostly focus on composition, and they weren’t _new_ ideas at the time either. For that matter, composing structures predates the concept of OOP.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann • that'd be **aggregation**; **composition** is one-or-more interfaces.  I had to look up the term in the GoF book.

Comment: I don't think `dynamic_cast` is needed... Simply call the appropriate interface method. Furthermore, I would elaborate a bit more on how composition is used (eg. add some code to the example). This idea is mostly how Java "solves" the MI problem.